# Draw line on ImageButton ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton in my asp page and i want when click on the loaded image the horizontal line will appear on the image.
I want that with c# code in imageButton onClick event not in javascript.
I want show lines when i click, like this image
[image]
 I have this Code in aspx page

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
 <!--Content Here-->
     <asp:ImageButton  ID="Image1" runat="server" OnClick="Image1_Click">


</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

can anyone help me, Thank you

Comment: Could you show a mock up on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want the line to become part of the image, or just to overlay the image?  You could have the "starting" image as the background for the button, and when you click the button, set a picture of a line as the image on the imageButton...

Comment: just to overlay the image, then i want to drag the line and change it's location using onMouseMove event